# Can I get Safari Dev Tools to ignore / blackbox jQuery scripts?

Tags: jquery, black-box, safari-web-inspector

Is is possible to setup Safari's web inspector to ignore jQuery while stepping thru JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this now by either adding a regex to match the script name, or by clicking the eye icon that appears on hover over the filename in the left side of the Sources panel.

https://webkit.org/web-inspector/web-inspector-settings/